# laravel schema builder timestamps

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create a simple NO DATES country table,
this is my migration code:

```
    Schema::create('countries', function($table)
    {
        $table->string('code2',2);
        $table->string('title',50);

        $table->primary('code2');
    });
```

weirdly "artisan migrate" creates automatically the columns: created_at & updated_at.

I tried to find how to disable it but no solution in the docs,
any ideas?
or should I removed the columns myself after the table is created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, this code works good as I wanted.

for anyone who will pass threw here:

this is how you remove a column -->

```
$table->dropColumn('votes');
```

and this is how you add the columns "created_at" & "updated_at" -->

```
$table->timestamps();
```